# How to construct a dynamic String in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to do something in my Application but I am stuck & unable to find a way forward. Here is my problem:-

I want to create Oracle Queries programatically. 2 such queries for e.g. are DROP TABLE tableName & ALTER TABLE tableName PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2, col3....);

In my class i have created these 2 final static Strings :-

```
private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE %1$s";

createDropStmt() {
    System.out.format(DROP_TABLE, tableName);
}
```

As you can see, this approach will work fine with DROP statements but not with PK's beacuse I don't know how may columns are going to be there till runtime. (private static final String PRIMARY_KEY = "ALTER TABLE %1$s PRIMARY KEY {don't know what to put here}"`)

So, my question is how to do this kind of thing for PK so that my template string can dynamically take values & construct the query.? Does Java have a clean way to do it or my approach should be different?

Thanks

Comment: How will the DDL statement exactly look like for the primary key case? I just need a little more info to imagine what values are used in your case.

Comment: DDL statement for PK will look like this :-ALTER TABLE orders ADD PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID, ITEM_NO, ITEM NAME);

Comment: Thanks, I oversaw that you already mentioned sth. like that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple primary key columns then you have to join their names with commas. The `java.util.Formatter` doesn't offer a way to concatenate arrays or lists of values. You have to do that for yourself.

When you don't want to write your own joiner, you could use the [Joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) from the [Guava libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) like this:

```
Joiner.on(",").join(primaryKeyColumns);
```

and then insert this into the ALTER TABLE statement.

Comment: Commons Lang also has StringUtils.join

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at PreparedStatement.

There are also some frameworks around that simplify sql usage in Java (http://www.jooq.org/ as one random example).

I really would not use String concatenation for query-construction. Its in the OWASP top 10 (sql injection).

Comment: a) You cannot use bind variables for table names.  b) You'd still have the same problem with the flexible number of parameters (for that primary key case).

Comment: I don't want to execute the query. I just want to put those created queries in a file.

Comment: sorry I got Your question wrong. Something like Apache Velocity might bring in some flexibility to create actual string from a parametrized snippet.